# Does hazelcast jet send/receive data from cluster

Tags: hazelcast-jet

We have hosted a Hazelcast cluster on a server and a different app on a different server in the same region uses Hazelcast Jet client instance to aggregate the data from Kafka source using pipeline.

In this setup, does Jet client instance send data which it receives from Kafka source Hazelcast cluster which will involve lot of IO or when we create pipeline, the Hazelcast cluster itself creates the connection to Kafka and this connection is from the Jet cluster rather than from the client app?

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek, you need to have a Jet cluster somewhere. The job itself run on the Jet cluster. If you have Kafka as a source, your app will submit the job to Jet cluster and Jet cluster will connect to data. If your sink is a Hazelcast map on the same Jet cluster, it'll be a local write, if it's a separate Hazelcast cluster, then you need to use `Sinks.remoteMap` configuring a client to connect to remote Hazelcast cluster.

Comment: Thanks @Gokhan for clarification. If the client app has multiple instances and all install running in hot hot mode (all instance are processing the data) in such setup each instance will submit the same job to the cluster, will jet cluster identify the same job or it will be duplicate and the result will be inconstant?